# How to map alt backspace to some command in .inputrc?

Tags: inputrc

Does anyone know how to bind key combinations with Alt in inputrc?

I want to map a key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to `backward-kill-word`, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to see what characters it represents, it shows `^[` for a brief moment before getting deleted or doesn't show anything at all.

I know that in order to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to something I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which will type `^[[1;5C` and then replace `^[` with `\e` and finally write add this line to `.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```

But this method doesn't work for me with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(literally anything)</kbd>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For keys that normally send a single character, Alt+key normally sends the escape character followed by this character. In particular, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> sends `\e\177` where `\e` is the escape character (represented visually as `^[`) and `\177` is the backspace character (represented visually as `^?` — more properly this is the delete character, but I'll use the name “backspace” in this answer). (Depending on your configuration, the backspace character may be `\b` instead, represented visually as `^H`.)

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the Ctrl+V character tells the terminal (or the application, depending on the terminal mode) to interpret the next character literally, so this inserts an escape character, which is represented visually as `^[`. Then the terminal has one more character to read, which is a backspace, which erases the escape character that you just entered.

To see the complete character string sent by a key, you can use this command, and type the key within 2 seconds:

```
stty raw; sleep 2; echo; stty cooked
```

`stty raw` switches the terminal to raw mode where control characters are just inserted as-is, and `stty cooked` switches it back. In practice <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is one of the very few cases where this is necessary though: most key chords only send either a single control character, or an escape character followed by printable characters.

In `.inputrc`, to cover both common cases (with the delete or backspace character):

```
"\e\177": backward-kill-word
"\e\b": backward-kill-word
```

Note that the escape sequence depends on your terminal. Some terminals don't send an escape sequence for some key chords, or send non-standard escape sequences, possibly the same for multiple key chords. But if you see `^[` briefly when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it shows that your terminal does the standard thing for this particular key chord.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation and the solution.